# How to create a compound index so that an account same phone number twice?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create compound unique index for my user account. In my schema I'm having 'category, email and phone number'. User can have same email id for different categories for example

```
example@example.com buyer
example@example.com seller
```

I achieved this by following lines `UserAccountSchema.index({userName: 1, userCategory: 1 }, { unique: true });`

Like this I would like to have

```
example@example.com buyer  94xxxxxxx
example@example.com seller 94xxxxxxx
```

How can I create a compound unique index like this?

Comment: Why not just add `phone` in your existing index?

Comment: Like this {userName: 1, userCategory: 1, phoneNumber: 1}

Comment: Yes, it will work as your existing index is already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your existing index and add `phoneNumber: 1` in it:

```
UserAccountSchema.index({userName: 1, userCategory: 1, phoneNumber: 1 }, { unique: true });
```